# Best practice for accessing a specific child window from the parent's wndproc

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2017

I keep running into scenarios where, from  a parent window's wndproc function, I must modify a child window (ex: clicking a child button adds to a sibling combobox; sending a message to the parent which it then forwards to the appropriate child). As far as I can tell, this means somehow obtaining the child's HWND reference and calling the child's wndproc with that reference.

In such a situation, I have the child's child-window-identifier, and I have the parent window's HWND reference, but nothing else.

From various tutorials, it looks like my only options are to either save the child's HWND reference as a global so I can access it from the parent's wndproc function, or call EnumChildWindows() and have a switch statement at the beginning which returns immediately if the current child is not the target child: The former doesn't seem to scale well because I'm saving a global for every child I will ever need to speak too; The latter seems to be intended for broadcasting to all children, instead of speaking to a single, specific child.

I *feel* like there's gotta be a function which takes the parent's HWND and the child's child-windows-identifier and returns the child's HWND, but no matter how I google, no such function appears to exist.

In short, I know a couple of ways to solve my problem, but I got a gut feeling I'm doing something wrong. What is the best-practice way to perform actions on a child window given the HWND reference for its parent?

Comment: HWND GetDlgItem(
  HWND hDlg,
  int  nIDDlgItem
); not only for Dialogs ,but all parent windows.

Comment: For one time operations that don't otherwise require the child `HWND`, you can also use one of the many `DlgItem` variations like [SendDlgItemMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-senddlgitemmessagew), [SetDlgItemText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setdlgitemtextw) etc.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most notifications based on [`WM_NOTIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-notify) or [`WM_COMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command), which includes [`BN_CLICKED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bn-clicked), carry the child's `HWND` as well as the child's ID, eg:

WM_NOTIFY

> wParam
>
> **The identifier of the common control sending the message.** This identifier is not guaranteed to be unique. **An application should use the `hwndFrom` or `idFrom` member of the `NMHDR` structure** (passed as the `lParam` parameter) to identify the control.
>
> lParam
>
> A pointer to an `NMHDR` structure that contains the notification code and additional information. For some notification messages, this parameter points to a larger structure that has the `NMHDR` structure as its first member.

WM_COMMAND

> wParam
>
> **The LOWORD contains the button's control identifier.** The HIWORD specifies the notification code.
>
> lParam
>
> **A handle to the button.**

So, in a parent window's message procedure, it knows exactly which child is sending a notification to it, and can access that child directly.

In the case where you want a parent's message handler to act on *another* child (ie, to add a string to a ComboBox from within a Button's click handler), should already have that other child's `HWND` or ID from when you initially created the child.

In the former case, you can use the saved `HWND` as-is, eg:

```cpp
HWND hwndCB;
HWND hwndBtn;

...

case WM_CREATE:
    hwndCB = CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOX, ..., hWnd, ...);
    hwndBtn = CreateWindow(WC_BUTTON, ..., hWnd, ...);
    break;

case WM_COMMAND:
    if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED) &&
        HWND(lParam) == hwndBtn)
    {
        SendMessage(hwndCB, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, ...);
    }
    break;
```

In the latter case, you can use [`GetDlgItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem) to get a child's `HWND` given its ID within the parent window, eg:

```cpp
case WM_CREATE:
    CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOX, ..., hWnd, (MENU)ID_MY_COMBO, ...);
    CreateWindow(WC_BUTTON, ..., hWnd, (HMENU)ID_MY_BTN, ...);
    break;

case WM_COMMAND:
    if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED) &&
        LOWORD(wParam) == ID_MY_BTN)
    {
        HWND hwndCB = GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_MY_COMBO);
        SendMessage(hwndCB, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, ...);
    }
    break;
```